# UINavigationController - pop animation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have trouble with animation of UINavigationController.
I have master-detail view. On view one button, that's open detail view. 
Detail view opens correctly, with normal animation of header and with sliding of content. But when I click Back button, header animated correctly, and content of detail disappear in moment and not animated.
Here is the link on demonstration of problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4UApAhEhx8

For opening I use standard

```
AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
```

I tried to pop view with code, no with back button, but there is same problem.

Comment: http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/navigationcontroller/

Comment: If it is not working.Please post your code used for popping the View controller

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Do you have any code in -viewWillDisappear: of the details view controller?

Answer (score 13):

This happens if somewhere in your code you are either forcing a call to one of the `viewWillAppear` counterparts with `YES` or `NO` instead of letting iOS decide, or if you mismatch calls to `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` with `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: +1 I've been looking for the cause for days. Tracking down the call mismatch did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Miha's answer pointed me in the right direction. In my case,  I had a custom UITabBarController in which I was doing some processing in viewDidAppear. The problem was caused by the absence of `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` in my viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same question as yours, and my problem is I set the selectedindex of tab bar in viewwillappear method of some view controller, this causes some bug of the navigation bar.

So I just simply move the code to viewdidappear, this fix the bugs.

Hope some day you may see this, even though you may already solve this. So hope this will help others.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the code for back to the previous window:

**[self.navigationController pushViewController animated:YES];**

I think it will help you.

Answer (score -2):

Please use the code for back to the previous window:

```
[self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];
```