# UINavigationContoller loses track of views after returning from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, stack

I have an `UINavigationController` setup as the `rootViewController` in a `TabBarController` in an iOS7 only app. Navigation works great: I can push new views and navigate back with either the back button in the top left corner or by swiping back / pop gesture.

But if I put the app in the background with anything but the root view shown in the navigation controller I run into this problem:  If I use the swipe back gesture there is no pop animation - the view disappears instantly and I am left with the underlying view. The lack of the swipe animation is not a big issue but the real problem is that the title in the navigation controller is now off. It still thinks that I am on the view controller that just disappeared!

For example:

My root view in the navigation controller will have the title **"Settings"** - I will then push the "**Appearance"** VC, put the app in the background using the home button - re-open the app and then try the swipe back gesture.  This pops me back to **"Settings"** but the title still says **"< Settings | Appearance"**. And now if I push another VC the title will say **"Settings"** on the new VC and there is no back button!

This only happens if I use the pop gesture - not if I use the navigation bar back button.

I have tried to check if the issue is that my VC becomes dealloc'ed by putting `NSLog` in the dealloc but that is not the issue.

I have also tried putting an:

```
NSLog("Hierarchy: %@",  [self.navigationController viewControllers]);
```

in both view will appear and disappear to see if the stack on the nav controller is getting messed up - but that is not the issue - the stack is correct.

Any suggestions for how to further debug or for what I may be doing wrong are much appreciated! This happens both on my iPhones and in the simulator and it is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was finally able to figure out what was going on thanks to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945415/492505

Turns out that I was running the following: `[[self.tabBarController selectedViewController] viewWillAppear:NO];` in my application did become active.

Hope this helps someone else.