# while pop a viewController, the left to right animation of View disappear

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

iOS 7, while pop a viewController,  the left-to-right animation of View's contents disappear. but the title-change animation of NavigationBar still exists.

I use this code to pop:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

some times this case will happen, sometimes not

I would like to know :

1. is this only about iOS 7?
2. what I do will absolutely trigger this animation problem happen.
3. how to solve this.

appreciate your answers.

Comment: Do you have a UINavigationControllerDelegate?

Comment: did not use UINavigationControllerDelegate, question solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question ended, This is the answer:
[Link of Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376892/uinavigationcontroller-pop-animation-bug?rq=1)

The Answer of [Miha Hribar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165708/miha-hribar) can solve my problem.

my solution detail:

the animation has problem, so finally, the reason is about UINavigationController, not it's viewControllers(at very first, I think the bug is caused by calling viewController's lifecycle method forcelly, like below:

```
[viewController viewWillAppear:YES]
```

so I solve this question by remove the following code:

```
// these codes are deleted
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
[nav viewWillAppear:YES];
```